# Getting a bitmap from gallery using Delphi via JNI, fails with Delphi XE7, works with Delphi XE6

Tags: android, delphi, bitmap, java-native-interface

I'm getting a bitmap using Delphi XE7 from android gallery using jni. Same code, worked using Delphi XE6:

```
unit home;

interface

uses
  FMX.Platform.Android, Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNI.App, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.JNI.Net, Androidapi.JNI.Provider, Androidapi.JNI.Media, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Messaging,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Objects, FMX.Surfaces, Data.DB, MemDS, DBAccess, MyAccess, Strutils,
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ToolBar1: TToolBar;
    SpeedButton1: TSpeedButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    const ScanRequestCode = 0;
    var FMessageSubscriptionID: Integer;
    procedure HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
    function OnActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent): Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.NmXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  FMessageSubscriptionID := TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SubscribeToMessage(TMessageResultNotification,
    HandleActivityMessage);
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  Intent.setType(StringToJSTring('image/*'));
  SharedActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent,0);
end;

procedure TForm1.HandleActivityMessage(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  if M is TMessageResultNotification then
    OnActivityResult(TMessageResultNotification(M).RequestCode, TMessageResultNotification(M).ResultCode,
      TMessageResultNotification(M).Value);
end;

function TForm1.OnActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode: Integer; Data: JIntent): Boolean;
var
  uri: Jnet_Uri;
  bitmap: JBitmap;
  surface: TBitmapSurface;
begin

  TMessageManager.DefaultManager.Unsubscribe(TMessageResultNotification, FMessageSubscriptionID);
  FMessageSubscriptionID := 0;

  if Assigned(Data) then
    begin
    try
      uri:=Data.getData;
      bitmap := TJImages_Media.JavaClass.getBitmap(SharedActivity.getContentResolver, uri);
      surface := TBitmapsurface.Create;
      JBitMapToSurface(bitmap,surface);
      // Fails here in Delphi XE7
      //Image1.Bitmap.Assign(surface);
    finally
        surface.Free;
        Result := true;
    end;

    end
    else Result := false;

end;

end.
```

Code fails in Image1.Bitmap.Assign(surface), I get a Fragmentation class error.

What's changed in Delphi XE7 to cause this error?

Comment: TBitmapsurface should be created before the try .. finally block

Comment: What is the exact error message text?

Comment: Finally and Free call not needed with ARC

Comment: I get a black screen, even in debug mode. One time, raised: "Project ....apk raised exception class segment fault (11)". With Delphi XE6, never fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

TThread.Syncronize( nil,
  procedure
  begin
    Image1.Bitmap.Assign( surface );
  end
);

Comment: It works on tablets, like samsung galaxy tab S, and fails on phones, like Samsung S4. But if the application is compiled with Delphi XE6, works on all devices. Compiled with XE7 or XE8, fails.